# pass httprequst as a parameter to a function (C#)

Tags: c#, httprequest

How could pass a httprequest as a parameter to a function?
Consider this function that is provided by another dll.

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.List<FIS.UAC_Security.Models.Organization> GetUserOrganizations(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest request, [int? userId = null])
```

how Could use this function?

Comment: I am new one in web programming and I try to define a httprequest variable, but I failed. I did some search on google by can not find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'this'* in the argument of the function indicates that its an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

so you can call it on request object itself:

```
var result = request.GetUserOrganizations();
```

or

```
var result = request.GetUserOrganizations(123);
```